# Using a list for a feature in an ML model

Tags: text, machine-learning, nlp, feature-selection

I want to run a machine learning algorithm on some data, so I'm exporting the data into a file first.

But one of my features for the text I'm classifying is a list of tags,
 and each text can have multiple tags ex. (["mystery", "thriller"]).

Is it recommended that when I write to my CSV file for exporting the data, that I write that entire list as one of the features for my data (the "tags" feature).
Or is it better to make a separate feature for each tag. The only problem then is that most examples will only have one tag, so the other feature columns for those will be blank.

So it seems like writing this list of tags as one feature makes the most sense, but then when parsing it for training, would I then treat every element of that list as its own feature still or no?

Comment: Whatever you do with them. In the end, when you supply them to the ML algorithm, they will be converted to different columns, one each for each different tag

Answer (score -1):

If you do it as a single feature just make sure to use some delimiter to separate the tags that won't occur in any of the tags, and also isn't a comma (as that will mess with the csv format), something like | would probably do fine. When you go to build your models and read in that list of tags you can then split it based on that delimiter. In Java this would look like:

```
String[] tagList = inputString.split("|");
```

I'm sure most languages will have a similar method to do this.

Comment: Right, that's actually exactly what I'm doing right now (using |). My real question (updated last line of my original question) is whether this is the recommended way to actually encode a list of the same kind of features. Should I have them be separate ones instead?

Comment: Choosing how to combine features is not a clear cut decision. It really comes down to experimentation and experience, as the results can vary wildly. In general I tend towards feature decomposition and prefer binary features, but this is by no means a hard and fast rule. Here is an article that talks a bit more about data preparation. http://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-prepare-data-for-machine-learning/